# Cannot get sys.argv to give any output in cmd

Tags: python, cmd, command, sys

This may seem really basic, but for some reason I cannot get any program with sys.argv to print in command line. Instead, a new cmd window is very quickly opened, displaying no text within itself, then closed. Immediately after this, cmd skips a line and prints `C:\Users\(my userid)>`, awaiting a new input.

my code is as follows:

first I tried:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

and ran it via command line by inputting:

`C:\Users\(my userId)\Desktop\filename.py`(the location of the file)

There was no output, and instead cmd did what I described in the first paragraph.

I next tried:

```
import sys

def main():
    print(sys.argv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and ran it via command line the exact same way. Again, I was greeted to the process described in the first paragraph.

I have checked that I have installed python the correct way, that the filenames are correct, and that the files are where they should be, generally speaking. I am running python 3.9.

Just inputting the filename results in the expected cmd output of:

```
'filename.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: moving the python file directly to C:\Users(my userID), then running it in cmd using filename.py results in the same issue as before, on both versions of the program.

Comment: You have to actually run Python. `python filename.py` or `python3 filename.py` or `py filename.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually run Python with `python filename.py` or `python3 filename.py` or `py filename.py`. This starts the interpreter and passes it the name of your file. The interpreter then executes the contents of your file.

```
C:\Users\TigerhawkT3>file.py
'file.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\TigerhawkT3>py file.py
['file.py']
```

Comment: turns out I really am dense, this works, cheers :)

will accept answer when I can in 5 minutes time (low rep user)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, sys.argv returns a list. The list[0] will be the your program filename and the rest (list[1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-sys-argv-in-python/), list[2], etc..) will be the arguments you input from the cmd line.

```
import sys
import time
def main():
  print(sys.argv[1])   # this will print out the first argument you input.
  time.sleep(3)        # in this case, sleep() is used to visualize the result in cmd.3 seconds in my case

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I hope this will help you out!
[Further Resource](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-sys-argv-in-python/)